# Setting up DVWA with XAMPP on virtual Ubuntu

Tags: linux, security, xampp

I've followed several sets of instructions, including an online recorded lecture, that show just copying the dvwa folder to /opt/lampp/htdocs and visiting localhost/dvwa in the browser with Xampp services started. I've attempted this, but this is the screen I get (instead of the DVWA page prompting me to log in and set up the database). [image: This screen indicates something what wrong, but I have no idea what]

What could the problem be? Has anyone run into this before? I've reattempted the instructions on this virtual computer and on my windows 10 host over the past few days and cannot get past this, even the slightest bit of advice would be incredibly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try browsing to http://localhost/ ? (Without the /dvwa/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Allow the usage of custom virtual hosts
   By default, xampp in ubuntu won't use the httpd-vhosts.conf file (the location of the virtual hosts), therefore we need to indicate that this file will be included during the runtime of apache. Open with your favorite code editor the httpd.conf file located tipically in /opt/lampp/etc or just execute the following command in your terminal to open a simple editor:

   sudo gedit /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf

Now locate yourself in (about) the line 487 where you probably will find the following lines:

```
# Virtual hosts
```

## Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

As you can see, the Include statement that includes the httpd-vhosts.conf file is commented. Proceed to modify the line uncommenting that line:

```
# Virtual hosts
```

Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

And you're ready to configure your custom vhost.

2. Create a custom domain in the hosts file of your system
   You need to create a custom domain where our apache virtual host will point to. This domain will be normally an ip (127.0.0.xx based) and a custom name.

To start, edit the hosts file located in /etc using your favorite code editor, or just by executing the following  command in the terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/hosts
```

And proceed to add your custom host. In this example, our ip will be 127.0.0.3 and the domain myawesomeproject. So finally, our hosts file will look like:

```
Save the file, and now the domain myawesomeproject is an alias for the local address 127.0.0.5.
```

3. Create your first virtual host
   Tipically, you need to create the virtual host in the httpd-vhosts.conf file located in /opt/lampp/etc/extra. Use your favorite editor to edit that file or just execute the following command to edit it in a terminal:

   sudo gedit /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

And create your own virtual host in this file. As shown in our custom domain in the vhost file of the system, the port that we are going to use is 127.0.0.5, therefore our virtual host will be:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.5:80>
```

DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/my-first-project"
  DirectoryIndex index.php

Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted

The deep and custom configuration of your VirtualHost is up to you. Save the file, and you're ready to test it.

4. Test your virtual host

   To test it, in the folder /opt/lampp/htdocs/my-first-project, create a simple PHP file 
   (index.php) that will contain the following PHP code:

Start apache, mysql (entire XAMPP) using the following command (or whatever the way you start apache and the other required services):

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Navigate in your favorite browser to http://myawesomeproject/ or http://127.0.0.5/ and you should get as output "Hello World" in the browser.